# SQL / OracleDB: How to set the same value for all fields in a column?

Tags: database, sql, oracle

Is it possible to set a value for all fields in a column, e.g.:

```
ID Host    URI
1  //cyrus /images    
2  //cyrus /videos
3  //cyrus /text
4  //cyrus /misc
5  //cyrus /backup
```

I want be able to *change all* the Host column entries -which are all alike- at *one* place. This place can be a GUI like the Ocracle SQL Developer or Queries, I don't care as long as I have to change only one datafield that changes all Host fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could do something like

```
UPDATE your_table_name
   SET host = '//new_host'
 WHERE host = '//cyrus'
```

to update all the rows in the table.  Storing the same data in multiple rows of a table, however, violates the basic principle of normalization.  You would almost always want to modify the schema design so that there is a separate table for the HOST and a foreign key from your table to the host table.  Something like

```
CREATE TABLE host (
  host_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  host_name VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
  your_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  host_id   NUMBER REFERENCES host( host_id ),
  uri       VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

If you did that, you'd only need to update one row in the `HOST` table to update the name of the host for all the rows in your table.

Comment: Great, I tried a foreign key relation b4, but maybe got the constraints wrong the first time - Ok so far so good, after that I do INSERT INTO "myDB"."HOST" (HOST_ID, HOST_NAME) VALUES ('1', 'TILSCHWEIGER'), and now I should enter a "1" into all HOST_ID fields of "your_table_name" ? At the moment there's still (null) there.

Comment: @Stephan - Correct, you'd want to insert a 1 into the `HOST_ID` column in `YOUR_TABLE_NAME`.  You'd want to insert the number 1 rather than the string '1' if you declared `HOST_ID` as a number-- you always want to insert strings into string columns, numbers into number columns, and dates into date columns.

Comment: You're correct once again, I used parentheses and inserted strings. Would you happen to know how to retreive a 'hostname' value in relation to 'host_id' from the 'your_table_name' table by using a DISTINCT statement? ... by the way, if one would want to avoid foreign keys, could I use joint table or is that considered bad practice?